# FileNotFoundException when loading API from URL. Java. Android

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

Im trying to return a JSON string from this api:
https://market.mashape.com/pareshchouhan/trivia

however Java is throwing the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://pareshchouhan-trivia-v1.p.mashape.com/v1/getAllQuizQuestions?limit=10&page=1
```

On the line

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

I have used similar code with other Rest APIs so i am a bit unsure why this is happenning.

```
    static String jsonStr;
    String data = "";


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BufferedReader br = null;


        try {

            URL url;
            String urlStr = "https://pareshchouhan-trivia-v1.p.mashape.com/v1/getAllQuizQuestions?limit=10&page=1";
            url = new URL(urlStr);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Mashape-Key", "4OFryNEYTWmshe8GheSnmIVEj7gZp1kJf6cjsncjVhXj9WYACn");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWr.write(data);
            outputStreamWr.flush();



            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            jsonStr = sb.toString();


        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to perform the wrong type of Request. This specific API did not support Get requests. Discovered this using https://www.hurl.it/

regardless, using the tutorial found here:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
I was able to change the request type and pull the correct data.

Hope this helps.